# why jquery code not running in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying it on jsfiddle...............i dont know why its not running...........someone help

```
html section
<html>
    <body>
        <div>The Answer is: </div>
        <div class='answer'></div>
    </body>`enter code here`
</html>


js section
function writeAnswer(answer) { // helper function for output
    $('div.answer').append($('<div>').text(answer));
}

function writedemo() {
    var answer="hello";
    writeAnswer(answer);

    }

}

writedemo();
```

Comment: How about a link to the fiddle so we can make sure you linked in the libraries correctly, used `onLoad()` correctly, etc

Answer (score 2):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zJ3yk/

because you got extra `}`

rest should help the needs `:)`

**code**

```
function writeAnswer(answer) { // helper function for output
    $('div.answer').append($('<div>').text(answer));
}

function writedemo() {
    var answer="hello";
    writeAnswer(answer);

    }
//} <===== this is the culprit and rest demo gives you idea. 

writedemo();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following jsfiddle. you can find working js.

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkant/HQyZe/8/